# Android Architecture Components and sectioned RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

Hi all dear android developers
im new to android, i started android developing with the [android-room-with-a-view-kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0) demo, it works good and no have any problem, but i want to add  section headers in recyclerview by first letters. i can create a sectioned recyclerview (multi type content recyclerview like [this](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/creating-a-recyclerview-with-multiple-content-types-and-layouts-in-kotlin/)), but my main problem is implementing a sectioned recyclerview that works whit ViewModel, Room, LiveData and ... . now how i do it?
thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by sectioned recyclerview, maybe you mean a recyclerview that has custom views? In general you just need to implement a custom adapter for the recyclerview. I wouldn't suggest using LiveData too much, it is very limited in the things you can do, instead use observables. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) is the official documentation on how you can create a custom adapter for the recyclerview.